# How can I change the border color when I hover a button with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to be able to change the borderColor when I'm hovering on my button because right now it keep the blue of the primary color.

here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
        },
    },
    btn: {
       fontFamily: "Manrope",
       borderColor: "#15e577",
       color: "#000",
       backgroundColor: "white", 
       "&:hover": {
           backgroundColor: "#15e577"
       },
    },

}));


export default function BtnContactUs() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let theme = createMuiTheme
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.btn}>
                Let's talk
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You just need to specify `borderColor` within the hover styling that you already have (currently only setting `backgroundColor`).

Comment: Wow, I was trying complicated stuff, and finally it was that easy. You are my savior !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the borderColor property

```
btn: {
       fontFamily: "Manrope",
       borderColor: "#15e577",
       color: "#000",
       backgroundColor: "white", 
       "&:hover": {
           backgroundColor: "#15e577",
           borderColor:"#564345"

       },
    },
```